# plotting defined function using ADF test

Tags: r

I have two time series `TS[,1]` and `TS[,2]`. And trying to
find lowest P value of ADF test in `TS[,1] - b*TS[,2]` by changing `b` which can make `TS[,1] - b*TS[,2]` stationary.

So I've working on plotting `p.value` versus `b` on graph but seemingly grammar problem stop me from proceeding more. When I calculate point like `pvalfun(1)`, it gives me answer as below. But When I try to plot `pvalfun` (defined as below), it give me back error message as below. Don't know why plotting `pvalfun` is not working.

Below is my code and error message.

```
 library(tseries)

 sprd <- TS[,1] - beta*TS[,2]
 ht <- adf.test(sprd, alternative='stationary', k=0)
 pval <- as.numeric(ht$p.value)

 pvalfun<-function(b){

 sprd <- TS[,1] - b*TS[,2]
 ht <- adf.test(sprd, alternative='stationary', k=0)
 return(as.numeric(ht$p.value))
 }

 x<-seq(-1,1,by = 0.01)
 plot(pvalfun(x))
```

> ```
> Warning message:
> In b * TS[, 2] :
>  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
> ```

```
pvalfun(1)
[1] 0.5090961
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pvalfun<-function(b){
  sprd = TS%*%rbind(rep(1,length(b)), -b) 
  U = apply(sprd, 2, function(c)  { ht <- adf.test(c, alternative='stationary', k=0)
                                    returnc(as.numeric(ht$p.value)) }
  return(U)
}
```

Comment: i just realized how "apply" efficient is in R. thanks